# Reflection method to Draw shape in C# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection, drawing

I have a blank method

```
void DrawShape(Graphics g, int x, int y){

}
```

I want to pass the "method body" as a string on runtime, to draw a shape by my code, ex:

```
y =0;
while(x<100){
 x++;
 g.drawRectangle(rec1, x,y);
}
```

and the method will execute like:

```
void DrawShape(Graphics g, int x, int y){
    y =0;
    while(x<100){
     x++;
     g.drawRectangle(rec1, x,y);
    }
}
```

It's will be wonderful, but I don't know how to do that. Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you tried the same?

Comment: You mean googling? I just think some accurate help will faster than blinding search, I searched for this before, too

Answer (score 0):

Look at dynamically compiling your code, but you need to pass an entire class definition (including `using` statements).

```
CodeDomProvider cdp = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#");
CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
cp.GenerateExecutable = false;
cp.IncludeDebugInformation = false;
// add assemblies if required:
// e.g. cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(...)

CompilerResults cr = cdp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, new String[] { sourceCode });
```

If there are no errors (`cr.Errors`) then you can access the dynamically generated types:

```
    Assembly a = cr.CompiledAssembly;
    Type[] types = a.GetTypes();
```

If your code only has one class definition, then types will have length 1. From here, you can invoke an instance of the type, and cast it to an interface you define.

E.g.

```
interface IDrawXYZ {
void DrawShape(Graphics g, int x, int y);
}

String srcCode =@"
using System;
using System.Drawing;
public class MyObject1 : IDrawXYZ {
   //...
}";
```

Or you can look for a static `MethodInfo` that accepts a `Graphics` object and two `int` parameters.